# Many world interpretation on test

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Is there any experiment conducted to prove Many world interpretation of Quantum mechanics?

If it can't be proved why we should take MWI seriously? Recently I read some papers of Max Tegmark who is an advocate of MWI and avoids the lack of experimental prove.

I think [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/97991/are-there-any-non-interpretational-arguments-in-favour-of-everetts-many-worlds?rq=1) is the same question as mine.

What about the two arxiv papers [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4422) and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9510007)?

Comment: Generally QM interpretations are just that - philosophical ascriptions of ideas to quantities that appear in the theory. By definition they are not testable, because QM is QM and it makes the same predictions no matter what interpretation you like. What many-worlds formulation do you have in mind that could even be considered testable?

Comment: What would you say about Max Tegmark when he says many worlds are as real as QM? @ChrisWhite

Comment: I can't understand your point. @AsphirDom

Comment: My point is that many worlds idea is not coming from physics and Max Tegmark DOES not know logic which is higher knowledge than any physics. That's why many physical theories are based on the principle of causality.

Comment: So, what would you say there is no other worlds besides ours? @AsphirDom

Comment: Exactly. If two worlds are somehow connected then they become one.

Comment: If they are different you can't observe them experimentally. So is it real if you can't see it? @AsphirDom

Answer (score 8):

MWI does not predict anything which could differentiate it from other interpretations of quantum mechanics. Otherwise it would be called theory rather than interpretation. The question of choosing particular interpretation is philosophical rather than scientific. If you dislike MWI you likely to choose another interpretation which would be similarly unprovable.

The main advantages of MWI are that it extends the area of applicability of the usual laws of quantum mechanics, and postulates that there are no distinguished observers.

The main disadvantage is that it postulates the existence of unobservable entities, far exceeding the observable domain.

It is also objectively deterministic but subjectively indeterministic, compared to totally deterministic Bohm mechanics interpretation and objectively indeterministic Copenhagen interpretation.

Comment: [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32501/many-worlds-how-often-is-the-split-how-many-are-the-universes-and-how-do-you?rq=1) is the real problem with MWI. It way misleads the philo-dudes.

Answer (score 1):

Hermetically contained parallel universes are one/observer. Given leakage, one suspects gravitation leaks first. The Hubble deep field denies universal gravitational lensing distortions.  Anything can be explained by curve-fitting.  Science begins with the arrival of falsifiable prediction.  Recently in the lay literature,

http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/2014/02/04/are-parallel-universes-unscientific-nonsense-insider-tips-for-criticizing-the-multiverse/#comment-12281

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any experiment conducted to prove Many world interpretation of Quantum mechanics?

Not that I know of, but Max Tegmark did propose an experiment that would prove the Many Worlds Interpretation to be the right one.

It is described on page 5 of [this](http://xxx.lanl.gov/PS_cache/quant-ph/pdf/9709/9709032v1.pdf) publication (thanks to @JoshuaLin in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233506/how-does-the-physics-work-for-the-quantum-suicide-thought-experiment/303916#303916) question):

[image]

The only caveat is, that it would be hard to obtain consensus within the physics community.